# XAuthority Error

Tags: 12.04, login, lightdm

When I try to login to my ubuntu 12.04 it accepts my account info and password but then a black terminal page appears and disappears very fast and it goes back to login page.
I killed lightdm and then used this command:

```
sudo lightdm
```

then tried to login (while terminal keeps the log). this is the error I receive:

```
Warning **error reading existing Xauthority: Error opening file : Permission denied Error writing X authority:Error opening file ,/home/sam/.Xauthority': Permission denied
```

All of this started when I pressed M in answer to this question during boot.
The Disk Drive for `/tmp` is not ready yet. S to skip mount or M for manual recovery

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7411037/) is the result to `sudo df /etc/fstab`

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7411040/) the result for `sudo cat /etc/fstab`

ask for more info if needed

Comment: @Simptnon I tried that didnt solve my problem still cannot login

Comment: I post my lightdm link again seems like there was something wrong with last one. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7413054/         I made a new user with this command now I can use my pc but wish I could recover last one

Comment: @Xubu-Tur well it was asking me for reputation to post the answer yesterday. Now it doesn't not sure what changed!!!

Comment: @Xubu-Tur my graphic seems lower since I fixed this problem.  maybe a graphic driver is also root permission and isn't running?? any fix to that?? I don't really know what is my ubuntu graphic driver otherwise I would reinstall it

Comment: some of hight definition videos that I could view easily before break and view large pixels.                                        http://paste.ubuntu.com/7418886/

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to a friend on `#ubuntu freenode channel` I fixed this problem.
First run this command to make sure your problem is same as mine:

```
ls -l .Xauthority
```

I got root:root as owner of .Xauthority which is the reason for me not being able to login from gui.
The owner should be like username:username.
Run this in Alt+Ctrl+F2 as root:

```
sudo chown user:user /home/user/.Xauthority
```

now you can login.

The reason for this error is that you probably run graphical programs through sudo like I used this command `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` should have used `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: You can mark the question as answered if you want then :)